# EC2 user-data Script Not Redirect `user-data.log` Output to Console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, user-data

## Description

Looking at this [AWS EC2 Doc](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-linux-log-user-data/) It should be possible to add `exec > >(tee /var/log/user-data.log|logger -t user-data -s 2>/dev/console) 2>&1` to a user-data script that is run on EC2 initialization.

When running `aws ec2 --region eu-west-1 get-console-output --instance-id i-<id>  | grep "user-data"` (or searching for other patterns that should be present) none are found after the ec2 initialization.

## Goal

To read the results and debug information from this initialization script without needing to SSH into the ec2 instance and poll the logs for the shutdown statement. Using the Instance shutdown as the "finished" state has a significant simplification on the deployment process for this repository.

## Question

What about this particular setup is not correct such that we are not getting logs out of the `aws ec2 get-console-output` command.

Alternative answer: What's a better method of retrieving the logs from an EC2 instance.

## User-Data Script

```
#!/bin/bash -xe
# redirect output to log file and console
exec > >(tee /var/log/user-data.log|logger -t user-data -s 2>/dev/console) 2>&1

if [ -n "postgresql,jq" ]
then
        yum -y -q update
        echo "complete: yum update"
        IFS=', ' read -r -a REQS <<< "postgresql,jq"
        for REQ in "${REQS[@]}"
        do
                yum -y -q install $REQ
                echo "complete: yum install $REQ"
        done
fi

echo "EC2P: ENTERING BOOTSTRAP SCRIPT....."

export PGPASSWORD=$( aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id <secret_arn> --query SecretString --region eu-west-1 | jq -r . | jq -r .password)

aws s3 cp s3://<query_object> /tmp/postgres-query.sql

echo  "EC2P: Starting PSQL Execution"

psql    -h <host> \
                -p 5432 \
                -U <user> \
                -o /tmp/postgres-query-result.txt \
                <db_name>_db \
                < /tmp/postgres-query.sql \
                > /tmp/postgres-query-output.txt 2>&1

echo "psql exit code is $?"

echo  "EC2P: PSQL Execution Complete"


# since instance_initiated_shutdown_behavior = "terminate"
echo "shutdown"
shutdown
```

## Terraform Declaration Of EC2 Instance

```
resource "aws_instance" "ec2_provisioner" {
  count                                = var.enabled ? 1 : 0
  ami                                  = data.aws_ami.ec2_provisioner.id
  iam_instance_profile                 = var.iam_instance_profile
  instance_initiated_shutdown_behavior = "terminate"
  instance_type                        = var.instance_type
  root_block_device {
    volume_type           = "gp2"
    volume_size           = "16"
    delete_on_termination = "true"
  }
  subnet_id = var.subnet_id
  tags = merge(
    {
      "es:global:component-name" = "${var.component_name}-ec2-provisioner",
      "Name"                     = var.name
    },
    jsondecode(var.additional_tags)
  )
  user_data = templatefile(
    "${path.module}/user_data.tpl",
    {
      BASH_SCRIPT = var.bash_script,
      PACKAGES    = join(",", var.packages)
    }
  )
  volume_tags = {
    "Name" = var.name
  }
  vpc_security_group_ids = [var.security_group_id]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The core issue here is that our initialization of the instance is producing too much console output

```
74295 # > 64 KBs
```

Which is hitting a [size limit built into the `get-console-output` command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/get-console-output.html)

> By default, the console output returns buffered information that was posted shortly after an instance transition state (start, stop, reboot, or terminate). This information is available for at least one hour after the most recent post. Only the most recent 64 KB of console output is available

The solution we're going with to fix this issue to to enable SSM and to log into parse the log output.

Comment: When i try the command, I get the error msg: syntax error near unexpected token `>' Even the link aws doc https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/ec2-linux-log-user-data shows the same syntax for exec > > command, but I am getting the above error. My bash version 4.4.20